# How can i filter result if i have array in body

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a payload

```
{
    "category": "Mobile",
    "price": {
        "from": "10",
        "to": "50"
    },
    "location": [
        "Jakrta",
        "Bandung",
        "Surabaya"
    ],
    "rating": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

i want to find all object which have rating 1 or 2 or 3 and also have any location
Basically i am creating a filter for an ecommerce store i which we will get multiple location and multiple ratings as well so we will return only those object which have matched property. i am attaching a screenshot of UI for better understanding.
[i want to run this filter with multiple location and multiple checked checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxlwU.png)

Comment: If you can access that data in the object, you can simply make a  [`.filter()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that acts on it. Also I assume you have an array of object payloads, rather than just one object?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Did you saw the attached img ?? i will recieve an object as payload i want to return those results which have 
 category : mobile
price range : from - to
location : any of checked one
rating : any of checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do create a filter dynamically:

```js
const { category, price, location, rating } = req.body;

const filter = {};

if (category) filter.category = category;
if (price) filter.price = { $gte: parseInt(price.from, 10), $lte: parseInt(price.to, 10) };
if (location?.length) filter.location = { $in: location };
if (rating?.length) filter.rating = { $in: rating };

const data = await Collection.find(filter);
```

Comment: Definitely agree that this is the general approach.  One note is that there might be additional translation needed for some of the filters, such as converting the `price` stuff to range predicates (eg `$gte` and `$lte`)

Comment: Actually it is not working in my case

Comment: What exactly does not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your objects, you should use filter() from your array :

```js
const arr = [{
    "category": "Mobile1",
    "price": {
        "from": "10",
        "to": "50"
    },
    "location": [
        "Jakrta",
        "Bandung",
        "Surabaya"
    ],
    "rating": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
},
            {
    "category": "Mobile2",
    "price": {
        "from": "10",
        "to": "50"
    },
    "location": [
        "Jakrta",
        "Bandung",
        "Surabaya"
    ],
    "rating": [
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}];

const result = arr.filter(el => el.rating.includes("1") || el.rating.includes("2") || el.rating.includes("3"));

console.log(result);
```